# jqBootstrapValidation() is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have tried everything and the only function that doesn't work in my jQuery is `jqBootstrapValidation()`. I really don't know why! Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code, I’m using `Vue.js`.

```
<style></style>
<template>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="settings" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="settings-name">
                     <h3>Name</h3>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="settings-email">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <h3>E-Mail</h3>

                        <input type="email" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="settings-password">
                     <h3>Password</h3>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a password.">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name='password' type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter new password" data-validation-matches-match='password' data-validation-matches-message='passwords do not match' required data-validation-required-message="Please re-enter a password.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="settings-save">
                     <h3>Save</h3>

                    <button type='submit' v-on="click: saveAccountSettings">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    var $ = require('jquery')
    module.exports = {
        methods: {
            validate: function() {

                $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
                    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
                        console.log('error')
                    },
                    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
                        console.log('success')

                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you loading the script that defines it? It's not part of jQuery itself.

Comment: So you're saying that jqBootstrapValidation() is not part of jquery?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it's this: https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

Comment: I'm loading bootstrap and jQuery in.

Comment: Oh I see! So it doesn't come with the bootstrap package. Oh gosh! Thank you so much!